# Word Vba Get a picture to document based on its position in file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to do a bit more than just grab a picure from a file. I need to make it so that a person can just upload a folder of 6 photos, and the macro will do its thing. Regardless of the file names. Is there something like index values for this? Can I define the pictures by their position?

I am thinking:

```
Sub PicturePull ()
    Dim Pic as Integer
    DimPicName as String
    PicName = >>?!?!?!?!<<
    Pic = 1
    Do while Pic < 7
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
            "\\agcfp01\users\cjones\desktop\Russells Template\Thermography Photos\Real\" & PicName _
            , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        Pic= Pic + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Dir(folderPath & "*")` to loop though all files in a given location.  If you know the expected type of file then you can use (eg) "*.jpg" instead of just *

Comment: would this replace the `.AddPicture` or the `PicName`??

Comment: I will post some suggested code - give me a few minutes...

Comment: Thank you, this would get me out of work an  hour early if it is as good as it sounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub PicturePull()
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim i As Integer, PicName As String

    SourceFolder = "C:\Users\ggggg\Desktop\Pictures\"

    i = 0

    PicName = Dir(SourceFolder & "*")
    'or (eg)
    'PicName = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.jpg") 'jpg only...

    Do While Len(PicName) > 0
        i = i + 1
        If i > 6 Then Exit Do
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=SourceFolder & PicName, _
                                LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        PicName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: All of a sudden this is only copying every second image, thoughts??

Comment: Works for me.  Did you make any changes?

Comment: extensive got it working again when i stripped it right back. minor typo went from go left to highlight followed by delete. My Bad